# Checking convergence of the improper integral $\int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log{x}}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My approach: I am using $\mu$-test to find if there exists a finite value for the function $$(x-1)^{\mu}.f(x)$$ as $x \to 1$  ; $f(x)$ being the integrand. So after applying L-Hospital rule, I get the limit as $0$ which is independent of $\mu$. Thus I can conclude that the Integral is convergent.
My question is whether this approach correct? As I am not sure if limit has to be **non-zero finite value**. Please help if there is any alternate method.
[image: Added screenshot of my textbook here]

Comment: Since $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}$ is the definition of $\ln^\prime1$, i.e. $1/1=1$, $\lim_{x\to1}(x-1)^\mu f(x)=1$ for $\mu=1$. So the limit is **not** independent of $\mu$.

Comment: @J.G. I meant to say that I can choose any positive $\mu<1$ which will satisfy the limit to be $0$

Comment: @J.G. I have added screenshot of my textbook which says the opposite. So am I using the formula incorrectly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\ge 1$ we have $\sqrt{x}\ge 1$ and we also have $\ln(x)\le x-1$ for all $x>0$ (easily provable by studying the derivative sign, maximum in $1$ which is $0$).

So $\displaystyle\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln(x)}dx\ge \int_1^2\frac{1}{x-1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx\quad$ which is divergent as $\lim\limits_{x=0}\ln(x)=-\infty$